# Input param not working as conditional switch in Nextflow processes

Tags: nextflow

I am trying to pass in a parameter to Nextflow that I can use to turn a process on or off, to no avail.

Moreover, when I print the parameter in the log file the case always changes, which seems odd to me (i.e., TRUE turns to true). I have tried setting the conditional statement to match "TRUE" or "true", given this behavior, but neither seems to work.

Here is some code to illustrate the issue.

```
params.force = "FALSE"
params.in = 1

log.info """\
         Force: $params.force
         """
         .stripIndent()

process tester {
  input:
    val x from params.in

  output:
      stdout testerOut

  when:
    params.force == "TRUE"

  script:
      """
      echo "foo"
      """
  }

  testerOut.view()
```

If this file is saved as testnf and is run via "nextflow run testnf --force "TRUE" " the process will not run. The output is:

N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.0
Launching `testnf` [soggy_lorenz] - revision: a7399aad3c
Force: true

[-        ] process > tester -

The goal is for users to pass in parameters that turn off or on certain processes. This seems like a common use case, but I am stuck. Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pallie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10524064/pallie) is correct:

> Nextflow automatically converts the --force TRUE param to a boolean

This is because the Nextflow command-line parameter values `TRUE` and `FALSE` (case insensitive) are special and will return `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`, respectively<sup>[1](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v21.10.0/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/cli/CmdRun.groovy#L470-L482)</sup>. When you print (or log) these parameters, you are  really just accessing a [Boolean](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_booleans) that represents the special truth values: `true` and `false`.

Be aware that parameters defined inside your Nextflow script will not be coerced. For example, setting `params.force = "FALSE"` inside you script will just give you a plain old [java.lang.String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) if `--force` is not specified on the command-line. The problem is that if you *do* specify `--force` on the command-line, you'll get a different type: a [java.lang.Boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html). The solution is to set `params.force` to a Boolean value inside your script:

```
params.force = false

println("Force: ${params.force}")


process test {

    echo true

    when:
    params.force

    """
    echo "foo"
    """
}
```

Some tests, with expected results:

```
nextflow run test.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `test.nf` [clever_mccarthy] - revision: e7a5148ea1
Force: false
[-        ] process > test -
```

```
$ nextflow run test.nf --force
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `test.nf` [distraught_jepsen] - revision: e7a5148ea1
Force: true
executor >  local (1)
[d0/c9a3d2] process > test [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
foo
```

```
$ nextflow run test.nf --force FALSE
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `test.nf` [astonishing_feynman] - revision: e7a5148ea1
Force: false
[-        ] process > test -
```

```
$ nextflow run test.nf --force True
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `test.nf` [sleepy_sammet] - revision: e7a5148ea1
Force: true
executor >  local (1)
[b5/9fac0f] process > test [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
foo
```

This last example shows that non-empty strings are coerced to `true` according to [Groovy truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth):

```
$ nextflow run test.nf --force foobar
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `test.nf` [trusting_hilbert] - revision: e7a5148ea1
Force: foobar
executor >  local (1)
[d1/c1b190] process > test [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
foo
```

Comment: Right, so the normally redundant checking for `params.force == true` would prevent running when with input ` --force foo` ?

Comment: @Pallie Correct, because "foo" and `true` are not equal. Since "foo" can be coerced to `true`, all you need is `when: params.force` like you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nextflow automatically converts the --force TRUE param to a boolean, so just change it to:

```
params.force = "FALSE"
params.in = 1

log.info """\
         Force: $params.force
         """
         .stripIndent()

process tester {
  input:
    val x from params.in

  output:
      stdout testerOut

  when:
    params.force

  script:
      """
      echo "foo"
      """
  }

  testerOut.view()
```

output:

```
$ ~/nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.6
Launching `main.nf` [high_hamilton] - revision: cac46af672
Force: FALSE

executor >  local (1)
[1e/5cb38e] process > tester [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
foo
```

Comment: The problem I have with your example is that it actually runs the test process when using `params.force = "FALSE"` (and `--force` is not specified on the command-line). This is might be unexpected unless you understand that non-empty strings, like "FALSE", are coerced to `true` according to Groovy truth.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say was that it's best to avoid mixing types. If `--force` is meant to be boolean and you want the default to be `false`, just set `params.force = false` in your script.